# Wallet.dat Corrupted help please?

Tags: wallet, wallet.dat

I bought bitcoins about a year half ago and my hard drive broke and i managed to recover them using a recovery tool that found wallet.dat from a deleted wallet on another hard drive but its courrped and wont work at all. i tired something to do wtih python dbdump.py --wallet but it failed, is there anything i can do any help would be great.The wallet.dat is only 112kb i dont know if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

You can attempt to launch the client via the command line and add the -salvagewallet option this attempts to recover and dump the private keys from the wallet.

Comment: i tried Pywallet 2.1.7 and it just keeps getting errors does this mean the wallet.dat is no use?

Comment: I once had a similar problem on a Linux box that had a simple permission error (owned by root running as standard user) but barring something like that it may not be recoverable.  I presume you have no other backup of the wallet?

Comment: i had many backups but that was 1.5 years ago but hopefully i find one of them or i get the old hard drive repaired some how fingers crossed.

Comment: Spinrite is worth checking out as far as hard drive recovery goes.  Well worth the price especially if your coin can be recovered.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [guide to corrupt Bitcoin Wallet recovery.](https://walletrecovery.info/how-to-recover-your-corrupt-or-deleted-bitcoin-core-wallet/)  The first thing I would try is [pywallet](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet). It can dump the private keys from your wallet to a file even if Bitcoin Core fails to salvage it.  You can then import them into a new wallet.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the information given [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=22697.0). I once managed to use it to recover wallets that resisted all other salvage methods I tried. (Casascius mentions full drive scanning in this post, but that is not needed if you have the wallet file).